# How to resolve an IllegalFormatConversionException

Tags: java

```
public class Experiments {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x;
        x = (1.3/100)*950;
        System.out.printf("1.3% of 950 is %1.2f", x);
    }
}
```

Running the program says:

> 1.3Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: o != java.lang.Double   at
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)    at
>   Experiments.main(Experiments.java:6)

Comment: Is this Java or C#? Please pick one and stick with it.

Comment: Your string formatting is wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want percent signs in your format string, you need to escape them:

```
System.out.printf("1.3%% of 950 is %1.2f", x);
```

Right now, Java tries to format the double with `%o` (octal notation) but this is only valid for integers.